# Getting a single array from an array of object

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to iterate through the array of object called sources at change event of my select input then pushing this single array to a new element conditionally

```
<template>
<div class="sourceselection">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> News List</h2>
    <h4>Select News Source</h4>
    <select class="form-control" @change="sourceChanged">
        <option v-bind:value="source.id" v-for="source in sources" :key="source.id">{{source.name}}</option>
    </select>
    </div>


    <div v-if="source">
        <h6 >{{source.description}}</h6>
        <a v-bind:href="source.url"></a>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
    name: 'SourceSelection',
    data () {
      return {
        sources: [],
        source: '',
      }  
    },
    methods: {
        sourceChanged (event) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.sources.length; i++){
                if (this.sources[i].id == event.target.value){
                  this.source = this.sources[i];
                }
            }
    }
},
    created : function () {
        this.$http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?language=en&apiKey=cf0866b5aaef42e995f9db37bb3f7ef4')
        .then(response => {
           this.sources = response.data.sources; 
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
}
</script>
```

i expect to pull the description into my h6 if the source exist

Comment: Can you provide more info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first create a state in `data` and name it `sourceId`,
then bind it to select `<select v-model="sourceId" class="form-control">`.

Now we need a computed filed which returns the source `return this.sources.find(s => s.id === this.sourceId)`

```html
<template>
  <div class="sourceselection">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> News List</h2>
      <h4>Select News Source</h4>
      <select v-model="sourceId" class="form-control">
        <option v-for="source in sources" :value="source.id" :key="source.id">
          {{ source.name }}
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div v-if="source">
      <h6 >{{ source.description }}</h6>
      <a v-bind:href="source.url"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SourceSelection',
  data () {
    return {
      sources: [],
      sourceId: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    source () {
      return this.sources.find(s => s.id === this.sourceId)
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?language=en&apiKey=cf0866b5aaef42e995f9db37bb3f7ef4')
      .then(response => {
        this.sources = response.data.sources;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why an extra computed property

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an event handler you can bind the selected value directly to your `source` data.

here is a demo:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      sources: [{
        id: '1',
        description: 'one desc',
        name: 'one'
      }, {
        id: '2',
        description: 'two desc',
        name: 'two'
      }, ],
      source: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select class="form-control" v-model="source">
    <option v-bind:value="source" v-for="source in sources" :key="source.id">{{source.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <h6>{{ source.description }}</h6>
</div>
```